# Python Error (in building pattern matching chatbot) : List object is not capable

Tags: python

Hello there I got error in my mini chatbot base on python.
In my CommandPrompt when I running there's an error message like this:
*TypeError: 'list' object is not capable*

Here is my code:

```
import re
import random

response = (
    ("hello",                ("Hi!", "Hello!", "Greetings!", "Howdy!")),
    ("hi",                   ("Hi!", "Hello!", "Greetings!", "Howdy!")),
    )

pronouns = {
    "i'm": "you're", 
    "i": "you"
    }

random.seed()
print("I am psychiatrist bot. I can make you feel better. Tell me how you're feeling!")

while True:
    input = re.split("[\.!?]",input("> ").lower().rstrip(".!?")) # <-- Error
    full_reply=' '

    for sentence in input:
        sentence=sentence.lstrip()
        for pattern in responses:
            wildcards = []
            if re.match(pattern[0], sentence):
                wildcards = filter(bool, re.split(pattern[0], sentence))
                # replace pronouns
                wildcards = [' '.join(pronouns.get(word, word) for word in wildcard.split()) for wildcard in wildcards]

                response = random.choice(pattern[1])
                response = response.format(*wildcards)
                full_reply+=response+' '

                break

    print(full_reply)
```

Comment: Kindly provide the complete error traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are overwriting (and then trying to use) the built-in function `input`; in the second run of your loop `input` will be a `list`.

and the error message is probably that a `list` is not *callable*.